# Fork and dup2 - Child process is not terminating - Issues with file descriptors?

Tags: c, linux, fork, dup2

I am writing my own shell for a homework assignment, and am running into issues.

My shell program gets an input `cat scores | grep 100` from the console ***and prints the output as expected but the `grep` command doesn't terminate and I can see it running infinitely from `ps` command.***

---

**EDIT - There was an error while closing fds. Now grep command is not executing and console output is -**

***grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor***

---

I am reading the number of commands from the console and creating necessary pipes and storing them in a two dimensional `int array fd[][]` before forking the first process.

`fd[0][0]` will contain read end of 1st pipe and `fd[0][1]` will contain write end of 1st pipe. `fd[1][0]` will contain read end of 2nd pipe and `fd[1][1]` will contain write end of 2nd pipe and so on.

Each new process duplicates its `stdin` with the read end of its pipe with the previous process and duplicates its `stdout` with the write end of its pipe with the next process.

Below is my function:

```
void run_cmds(char **args, int count,int pos)
{
    int pid,status;
    pid = fork();
    if ( pid == 0 )
    {
        if(pos != 0) dup2(fd[pos-1][0],0); // not changing stdin for 1st process
        if(pos != count) dup2(fd[pos][1],1); //not changing stdout for last process
        close_fds(pos);
        execvp(*args,args);
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid(pid,&status,0);
        count--;
        pos++;
        //getting next command and storing it in args
        if(count > 0)
            run_cmds(args,count,pos);
        }
    }
}
```

- **args** will contain the arguments for the command.
- **count** is the number of commands I need to create.
- **pos** is the position of the command in the input

I am not able to figure out the problem. I used this same approach for hard coded values before this and it was working.

What am I missing with my understanding/implementation of `dup2`/`fork` and why is the command waiting infinitely?

Any inputs would be greatly helpful. Struck with this for the past couple of days!

---

EDIT : close_fds() function is as below -
For any process , I am closing both the pipes linking the process.

```
void close_fds(int pos)
{
 if ( pos != 0 )
        {
        close(fd[pos-1][0]);
        close(fd[pos-1][1]);
        }
 if ( pos != count) 
        {
        close(fd[pos][0]);  
        close(fd[pos][1]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please check the return value of every system call you call (e.g. `fork`, `waitpid`, `dup2`, `execvp`). If they return an error code, please use `perror` or `strerror(errno)` to print the error. Please update the question stating that there were no errors. Please call `abort();` after `execvp` to make sure that the child process doesn't continue running.

Comment: Please post your entire program (http://sscce.org/) in a single .c file.

Answer (score 3):

#### First diagnosis

You say:

> Each new process duplicates its stdin with the read end of its pipe with the previous process and duplicates its stdout with the write end of its pipe with the next process.

You don't mention the magic word `close()`.

You need to ensure that you close both the read and the write end of each pipe when you use `dup()` or `dup2()` to connect it to standard input.  That means with 2 pipes you have 4 calls to `close()`.

If you don't close the pipes correctly, the process that is reading won't get EOF (because there's a process, possibly itself, that could write to the pipe).  It is crucial to have enough (not too few, not too many) calls to `close()`.

---

> I am calling `close_fds()` after dup2 calls. The function will go through the `fd[][2]` array and do a `close()` call for each `fd` in the array.

OK.  That is important.  It means my primary diagnosis probably wasn't spot on.

#### Second diagnoses

Several other items:

1. You should have code after the `execvp()` that reports an error and exits if the `execvp()` returns (which means it fails).
2. You should not immediately call `waitpid()`.  All the processes in a pipeline should be allowed to run concurrently.  You need to launch all the processes, then wait for the last one to exit, cleaning up any others as they die (but not necessarily worrying about everything in the pipeline exiting before continuing).

   If you do force the first command to execute in its entirety before launching the second, and if the first command generates more output than will fit into the pipe, you will have a deadlock — the first process can't exit because it is blocked writing, and the second process can't be started because the first hasn't exited.  Interrupts and reboots and the end of the universe will all solve the problem somewhat crudely.
3. You decrement `count` as well as incrementing `pos` before you recurse.  That might be bad.  I think you should just increment `pos`.

#### Third diagnosis

*After update showing `close_fds()` function.*

I'm back to "there are problems with closing pipes" (though the waiting and error reporting problems are still problems).  If you have 6 processes in a pipeline and all 5 connecting pipes are created before any processes are run, each process has to close all 10 pipe file descriptors.

Also, don't forget that if the pipes are created in the parent shell, rather than in a subshell that executes one of the commands in the pipeline, then the parent must close *all* the pipe descriptors *before* it waits for the commands to complete.

Please manufacture an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

You should create a program that manufactures the data structures that you're passing to the code that invokes `run_cmds()`.  That is, you should create whatever data structures your parsing code creates, and show the code that creates the pipe or pipes for the '`cat score | grep 100`' command.

I am no longer clear how the recursion works — or whether it is invoked in your example.  I think it is unused, in fact in your example, which is probably as well since you would end up with the same command being executed multiple times, AFAICS.

Comment: +Jonathan - I am calling close_fds() after dup2 calls. The function will go through the fd[][] array and do a close() call for each fd in the array.

Comment: Jonathan... I added the code for close_fds().
There was an error which I fixed now. Now grep command is not executing and console output is -

grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor. EDITED QUESTION

Comment: As I already asked you, please add error checking and error reporting to your code, update your code in the question, and specify which errors got printed.

Comment: @pts: was this comment intended for me or for the OP?  If it is for the OP, maybe it belongs under the question rather than my answer.  I agree 100% with your sentiment, though — there's no way to resolve the problem without having enough code to be able to see what's going wrong.  How are the pipes created?  How are the children forked?  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Most probable reasons why `grep` doesn't terminate:

- You don't call `waitpid` with the proper PID (even though there is such a call in your code, it may not get executed for some reason), so `grep` becomes a zombie process. Maybe your parent shell process is waiting for another process first (infinitely, because the other one never terminates), and it doesn't call `waitpid` with the PID of `grep`. You can find `Z` in the output of `ps` if `grep` is a zombie.
- `grep` doesn't receive an EOF on its stdin (fd 0), some process is keeping the write end of its pipe open. Have you closed all file descriptors in the `fd` array in the parent shell process? If not closed everywhere, `grep` will never receive an EOF, and it will never terminate, because it will be blocked (forever) waiting for more data on its stdin.

Comment: +pts - 
1. I am not able to see Z in the output of ps for the grep process. The grep seems to be waiting .  
2. I closed all the fds in the parent process but the second process (grep in this case) doesn't print anything on the console and keeps waiting.

Comment: I'm not able to help you more until you post your entire program as an http://sscce.org/